# Implementing Dynamic Metro Map Line Highlighting with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, blink

I have a challenge related to a metro map. There are two lines, violet and green. I want to implement a feature where clicking on the violet line makes it blink, and when I click on the green line, the violet line stops blinking and the green line starts blinking. I'm attempting to achieve this using jQuery. If you have any solutions or suggestions, please share them.

[image]

I attempted to incorporate this code, but for some reason, it doesn't seem to be functioning as expected.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour]. Please provide any examples of code that you have tried. Please provide a [mcve].